# Indefinite Integration issue

Tags: integration

$\int\frac{x\sqrt{\ln(x²+1)}}{x²+1} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\ln(x²+1)}$

how should I get $1/2$ ? 
I thought I could assume $\ln(x²+1)$ as u, but now I am lost

I thought it must be $1/u$ form to get the answer. If I used the method, I cant get $1/2$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Let $\sqrt{\ln(1+x^2)}=u\implies du=\dfrac1{2\sqrt{\ln(1+x^2)}}\cdot\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}dx$

$\iff\dfrac{x\sqrt{\ln(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2}dx=u^2du$